# How can I change UART configurations(# of stop bits, parity bits etc.) on ENERGIA IDE?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, uart, arduino-ide, texas-instruments

I need to use UART of TI CC3220s launchpad with 2 stop bits.
how can I change the UART configurations on energia ide like number of stop bits?

config parameters do not work (https://energia.nu/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/begin/)
the following error occurs:    'SERIAL_5N1' was not declared in this scope

Any help  will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit**
The link that you provided directly says:

> Serial.begin(speed) Serial.begin(speed, config)
>  **Arduino Mega only**

According to the code (I found), the `Serial` library of Energia-IDE is only a SoftwareSerial, that only provides the `begin(speed)` function (without a config).
Maybe you should have a look into that, so that you can adapt the function, for your own purpose.

**/edit**

In the Arduino-IDE, the `config`'s are defined in `HardwareSerial.h`. If the Energia-IDE uses the same library, you might try to use the same values instead.

```cpp
// Define config for Serial.begin(baud, config);
#define SERIAL_5N1 0x00
#define SERIAL_6N1 0x02
#define SERIAL_7N1 0x04
#define SERIAL_8N1 0x06
#define SERIAL_5N2 0x08
#define SERIAL_6N2 0x0A
#define SERIAL_7N2 0x0C
#define SERIAL_8N2 0x0E
#define SERIAL_5E1 0x20
#define SERIAL_6E1 0x22
#define SERIAL_7E1 0x24
#define SERIAL_8E1 0x26
#define SERIAL_5E2 0x28
#define SERIAL_6E2 0x2A
#define SERIAL_7E2 0x2C
#define SERIAL_8E2 0x2E
#define SERIAL_5O1 0x30
#define SERIAL_6O1 0x32
#define SERIAL_7O1 0x34
#define SERIAL_8O1 0x36
#define SERIAL_5O2 0x38
#define SERIAL_6O2 0x3A
#define SERIAL_7O2 0x3C
#define SERIAL_8O2 0x3E
```

At least this passes the "validate" step in the Energia-IDE:

```cpp
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600, 0x00);
}
```